# Regex to replace IP address

Tags: java, regex

75.122.1.23

I need to replace the third number with 2 so it looks like 75.122.2.23

What regex can match the third section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int replacementNumber = 2;
ip = ip.replaceAll("(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})", "$1.$2."+replacementNumber+".$4");
```

Commented form:

```
/^                 # match beginning
    (
        \d{1,3}    # one address segment
        \.         # separation dot
        \d{1,3})   # second address segment
    \.             # separation dot
    \d{1,3}        # address segment to be replaced
    \.             # separation dot
    (\d{1,3})      # last address segment
$/x                # match end, ignore comments
```

Comment: the regex seems fine, but preg_replace... in java ?

Comment: +1 for a regex that looks good. is it possible to write this in java?

Comment: This will also match 999.999.999.999 though.

Comment: Thanks for the regex, the java implementation is: `ip.replaceAll("(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})", "$1.$2."+replacementNumber+".$4");`

Comment: Oops!  Sorry folks, I watch the Java and PHP tags simultaniously and forgot to check which one this was under :)

Comment: @Oscar: good point, but he's not using it to _validate_ an IP address, only to _manipulate_ it.

Comment: ^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.
([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$

Answer (score 0):

```
^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.
([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$
```