# Using regex to replace URL in place?

Tags: java, regex

I am using a third party data service which allows for the input of a Java regex pattern. I do not have access to the code. Is there a regex pattern which would allow me to modify a string in place? I basically am getting in a URL but need to replace the URL with another address. For example I will get in: `http://10.12.344.211/someimage.png` and I want to replace **10.12.344.211** with another address.

Is there some type of find/replace using regex?

Comment: Is this IP address fixed or it can change? If it is fixed then you don't need regex.

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7191553/459185
 1. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7101935/459185

Comment: There's no "in place" replacement, but if your tool offers two parameters - the regex and the replacement term - then it can be done. However it looks like a simple non-regex replacement would work.

Answer (score 0):

If this IP address is fixed and it is part of String then you just can use `replace` method like

```
String someData = "address of this image is http://10.12.344.211/someimage.png";
System.out.println(someData);
someData=someData.replace("http://10.12.344.211", "http://127.0.0.1");
System.out.println(someData);
```

Output:

```
address of this image is http://10.12.344.211/someimage.png
address of this image is http://127.0.0.1/someimage.png
```

Otherwise you can use replaceAll with `"http://(\\d{1,3}[.]){3}\\d{1,3}"` as regex.

- `\\d` represents digit `[0-9]` range
- `[.]` represents dot literal
- `{x}` or `{min,max}` represents number of occurrences

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no `URL.setHost` method.

However you don't **really** need regex here.

For instance:

```
try {
    URL firstUrl = new URL("http://10.12.344.211/someimage.png");
    URL newURL = new URL(
        // note the new String ends with "212"
        firstUrl.toString().replace(firstUrl.getHost(), "10.12.344.212")
    );
    System.out.println(newURL);

}
catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
    mue.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
http://10.12.344.212/someimage.png
```